# Excel macro buttons created on quick access toolbar won't work

Tags: excel, vba

I added a macro to the Quick Access Toolbar in Microsoft Office Excel 365.

Normally, they work well, but after I added KuTools, some problems started occurring.

I have now disabled KuTools, but the problems persist.

The most important issue is that the QAT no longer works.

Later, while working in Excel, when I click the button for a macro, I receive the following error message:

> "Cannot run the macro 'macroname'. The macro may not be available in
> this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

I tried enabling all macros, but it had no effect. I checked disabled add-ins and found nothing, and the Trust Center settings are okay.

I can run the macros manually by pressing Alt+F11, but this defeats the purpose of having the macros in the first place (which is to save time).

After manually running the macro, the QAT buttons also start working.

Before running it manually, I am unable to work from the QAT or see any macros in the View => Macro's section.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a fix?

Thank you.

Comment: KuTools is difficult to uninstall cleanly according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1632475/how-to-uninstall-kutools-from-windows-10) post on SuperUser